# Create a region adjacency matrix from a labeled image

Tags: matlab, matrix, graph

I have an image matrix. After, I apply the superpixel algorithm to obtain the labeled matrix and I want to generate the adjacency matrix from this labeled image, my code is like that:

```
I=imread(myimage); 
SP=superpixelalgo(I);
```

How I can generate the adjacency matrix from `SP`?  I need something like what is described below:

[image: algorithm]

---

my code is like this:

my image of size 10x10

`I=`
[image: myimage]

// Applying my superpixels algo

```
L=superpixels(I);
L=
```

[image: my superpixel matrix]

the number of superpixels is:

```
SP=length(unique(L))=3; // so we have 3 regions
```

I want now to generate an adjacency matrix of size 3x3 for the regions

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with `superpixelalgo`. What is the `SP` that it returns?

Comment: Yes, Can you link us to superpixelalgo or provide an example output of it.

Comment: [Your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33352598/how-to-draw-communities-over-superpixels-matrix) implies you were already generating it...

Comment: Hi beaker and Huá dé ní, the SP is labeled matrix of the image, it have the same size the goal of SP is ti divide the image into region, for exemple region1 labeled by 1, region 2  labeled by 2.....etc.

Comment: Hi kmc, yes i generated but it seems that my algorithm was wrong, i want somthing like the picture in the link.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the most recent version of MATLAB (R2015b), then try the function adjacentRegionsGraph in the MATLAB Central File Exchange submission called [Image Graphs](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/53614-image-graphs).

Comment: Hey Steve sorry for the late,  I tried the function which you proposed to me, but i have a problem in the output because i want an adjacency matrix A(size(SP),size(SP)) for example if i have in the region image, 256 super pixels, so the adjacency matrix must be A(256x256), if you can help me for that i would be very thankful. Sorry another time for the late.

Comment: What is the size of the adjacency matrix?

Comment: the size of the adjacency matrix is length(Sp)Xlength(Sp) where Sp is the number of regions.

Comment: I understand. I meant what is the size of the adjacency matrix you got for your example with 256 super pixels? It would be best if you could post a sample image and the exact code that you used.

Comment: for example with 256 super pixels a got an adjacency matrix of size 256x256. Thank you in advance.

Comment: In your first comment, you said that you expected an adjacency matrix that is 256x256. In your most recent comment, you said you got an adjacency matrix that is 256x256. So can you please clarify your problem? In my last comment, I asked for you to post a sample image and the exact code that you used. You should also explain clearly how the result is different than what you expect. If you don't do that, then I likely will not have enough information to help you.